# Support for Polish characters with FPDF

Tags: php, character-encoding, fpdf

So I'm looking for a way to handle Polish characters in a PHP form submitted and processed in the same file (PHP_SELF). I know this is a pretty common topic here and I have tried the things I have found already here:

- `charset="UTF-8"` meta
- `accept-charset="utf-8"` in html form tag
- `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8')` in top of php file
- `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8')` in top of php file
- `utf8_decode` method

and combos of these.

It's how code looks like (roughly):

```php
    <?php
        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
        mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
    
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
          $name =$_POST['name'];
          $surname =$_POST['surname'];
          $question_1 = "";
    
          if (isset($_POST['question_1'])) {
            $question_1 =$_POST['question_1'];
          }

          // more of assigning answers
    
          $subject = "Formularz kontaktowy";
          $body =  "Imię i nazwisko: $name $surname\n";
          $body .= "Pytanie 1: $question_1\n";
          
          require('fpdf.php');
          $pdf = new FPDF();
          $pdf->AddPage();
          $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
          $pdf->Cell(0,10,utf8_decode($email_subject),0,1);
          $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
          $pdf->MultiCell(0,5,utf8_decode($email_body),0,1);
          $pdf->Output();
          
          // download pdf file (for testing)
          header('Content-type: application/pdf');
          header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="formularz.pdf"');
          readfile('formularz.pdf');
          unlink('formularz.pdf');
        }
        ?>
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pl">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- other meta tags -->
      </head>
      <body>
          <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" class="form-block" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
    
            <!-- INPUTS HERE -->
    
            <input name="submit" type="submit" class="form-submit" value="Wyślij" />
          </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

How I can tickle this to work out with my scenario?

## Edit

I have found that I have proper Polish letters when I echo but it's not working properly in FPDF.

Comment: Standard fonts don't support Polish. See [tutorial #7](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto7.htm) and [tFPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/?go=script&id=92).

Comment: And don't send HTML before or after the PDF.

Comment: ^oh... thanks -about sending pdf it's wrapped up around the "if submitted" statement

Comment: You don't call `exit` after sending the PDF, which means that the HTML is sent too.